# Is there a way to define the local profile in the config for Protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have Jasmine-Reporters set up in my config files and working great for me, locally:

```
require('C:/Users/**<me>**/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters')
var outputPath = "C:/Users/**<me>**/<myPath>/"
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(outputPath, true, true));
},
```

What I'd like to do now is to somehow make the path declarations dynamic so that my tests can be shared and run on someone else's machine.  I've tried just replacing my local profile with %USERPROFILE% but that didn't work.  Any hints as to how to do this?

Comment: if you are sharing your projects via github or similar, you could add a config file where every user specifies the path. ignore this file when pushing, so you don't overwrite it. maybe there is a way via nodes [process.platform](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform), but you wont get the username i guess

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this figured out.  What I ended up doing was to create a separate 'prop.js' file that just had this one line in it:

```
exports.username = "<myProfileName>";
```

Then, in my conf.js files, I can simply do this:

```
var properties = require('././prop.js');
var username = properties.username;
require('C:/Users/' + username + '/../jasmine-reporters')
```

That way, anyone on my team that I want to share these tests with only has to edit the prop.js file once with their own profile name.